# Git - Is it possible to commit a specific file that has multiple lineages of history which is selectively used by different users?

Tags: git

Consider a scenario,

We have a settings file called ".project", this file is required by the development environment, and therefore cannot be ignored.

However, the contents of this file are relevant only to an individual's PC and the location of the folders related to the project.

Is there any way that every user can have their own version of ".project" file in the repository? I understand that every user could hold their own version of the ".project" file in some way or another like keeping a file ".project_[name]" for every user in a folder location that can be copied out and loaded, but I is there a better way?

And if not, is there a better way than the method that I suggested?

Comment: Is this `.project` an Eclipse project file by any chance? If so then it shouldn't be relevant only to an individual's PC.

Comment: The thing you suggested—having a committed *template* file for users to copy and install as their (`.gitignore`-ed) *actual* file—is the standard solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: Your question is based on the faulty assumption that *"this file is required by the development environment, and therefore cannot be ignored"*. You certainly should ignore this file if it's specific to each person's development environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard solution here is to not commit the `.project` file. Add it to your `.gitignore`. You might want to commit a file called `.project-example` or something that users can copy as a basis for creating their `.project` files, or write some sort of setup script that writes a correct `.project` file for people to use after they have cloned the project. I'd strongly recommend you do something like the above.

Alternatively, everyone can have their own `.project-[name]` file and people can symlink their files to `.project` on their own machines. This works but isn't really recommended as different people's `.project` files are not really part of the overall project - any changes to them will just bloat the history of your repo.

If you really want to share the one `.project` file you might be able to achieve it with a "smudge filter". It will have to be configured by each user after they checkout their repo, but in theory it can let you customise the `.project` file for the user's environment, but still keep most of it in git.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on git smudge